# Redrawing Binary Tree Using Given Traversals

Tags: tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am not understanding how to draw a Binary Tree give traversals. Could someone explain to me inorder, preorder, and postorder traversals in a more efficient way?

For example:

Reconstruct the exact BINARY tree given the following traversals:

Inorder:

```
9, 2, 10, 6, 5, 8, 3, 1, 4, 7
```

Post order:

```
9, 10, 2, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 1, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the best example I've found explaining this is [here](http://nova.umuc.edu/~jarc/idsv/) (click 'Traversals' on the left menu, then 'Start Lesson' for the demo) as it has a completely pictorial explanation of what is happening

Short version

- Preorder is **DLR**: Data, Left, Right
- Inorder is **LDR**: Left, Data, Right
- Postorder is **LRD**: Left, Right, Data